# maven-android-sdk-deployer Updating .m2 Repo

Tags: android, maven

I have used the [maven-android-sdk-deployer](https://github.com/mosabua/maven-android-sdk-deployer) to build the libraries that I use in my project. This worked fine but now I would like to update the libraries that are in the repo. I would like the newest version of android currently I have 4.1.1.4. Also I would like to update the support library to version 11 as I need to use the childFragmentManager.

I ran mvn install and mvn clean install. But it will not add the new libraries that I require. I also updated the deployer with git pull and still the same problem

Am I missing something?

**Edit**

So it looks as tho the deployer put the android libraries in android/android/ in the .m2 repo. But the project is looking at the libraries in com.google.android how do I change this?

Answer (score 1):

You change the dependency in the project ..